# Autocomplete not able to select on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autoselect and facing an issue with mouse selection of `<li>` element

I am rendering it in following way

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

    if(item.category == "-") {
        return $("<li class=\"ui-menu-ac-item\" role=\"menuitem\"></li>").
            data("item.autocomplete", item).
            append("<a class=\"ui-corner-ac-all\" tabindex=\"-1\" "+
            " onclick='$(\"#writeRevSearch\").val(\""+item.label+"\");"+
                " $(\"#writeRevSearch\").autocomplete(\"close\");'>"+
                item.label +
                "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    } else {
        return $("<li class=\"ui-menu-ac-item\" role=\"menuitem\"></li>").
            data("item.autocomplete", item).
            append("<a class=\"ui-corner-ac-all\" tabindex=\"-1\" "
            +  "onclick='$(\"#writeRevSearch\").val(\""+item.label+"\");"+
                " $(\"#writeRevSearch\").autocomplete(\"close\");'>"+
             item.label +
            "<span>" + " in " + item.category + " " +"</span>"+
            "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    }
};
```

Problem is if use keyboard to select items, things are fine but if I use the mouse to select any item from drop down I get an error on this line:

```
var h=f.item.data("item.autocomplete"),i=a.previous; --->> here ( Telling cant call method data on undefined )
if(a.element[0]!==b.activeElement){
        a.element.focus();
        a.previous=i;
        setTimeout(function(){
            a.previous=i;
            a.selectedItem=h
            },1)
        }
        false!==a._trigger("select",c,{
        item:h
    })&&a.element.val(h.value);
    a.term=a.element.val();
    a.close(c);
    a.selectedItem=h
```

The data comes undefined only in case of mouse click and not on keyboard selection.